# how to use str.replace to clean every row of a column

Tags: python, pandas

It's seems to be very easy task but I can't get the code works.

I´m Just trying to clean tweet replies in a table and mantain only letters using the jupyter notebook on kaggle

The thing is no matter what code I use, it's like nothing happens

## I´m tried the following:

```
pattern=re.compile('\[].\\n')
dfreplies.Replies.str.replace(pattern, '',regex=True)
```

an example of the actual result is:

```
dfreplies.Replies
>>>     Replies
0       [I need \n, [[#] a soda please]
1       [bla bla + but nice hair, [[@],]
2       [Great idea https://www.music.pe, follow us]
```

I expect

```
>>>     Replies
0       I need a soda please
1       bla bla but nice hair
2       Great idea, follow us
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your expected output you need a more complex replacement like below:

```
In [256]: df['Replies'].str.replace(r'([\[\]#+@]+|\\n),?\s*|\s*https?://[^\s,]+', '', regex=True)               
Out[256]: 
0       I need a soda please
1    bla bla but nice hair, 
2      Great idea, follow us
Name: Replies, dtype: object
```

Comment: the code is not working when it´s seems to be right, that's the reason I write this post

Comment: @johnGuarenas, I've posted it right from my ipython console - so it's working. Otherwise - you have not prepared your question/conditions properly

Comment: The question is well asked, what happens is that the code is not having an effect on the Kaggle Kernel, I have already reported it.